# how to share content with newline on facebook using og graph tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sharing the content on facebook using og graph and yes its working well. I need to share the og:description with the html tags. I mean in my share content I need a new line.

For example: `meta property="og:description" content="hello how are you? \n whats up there ? \n Thank you."`

So when I share using https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?www.mysite.com/page.php, so on post activity my description text is without new line like "hello how are you? whats up there ? Thank you."

So can you please help me? Please suggest solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: i don´t think custom line breaks are possible

Comment: Not possible. If your description does not make sense without line breaks, then it is rather not a proper description in the first place.

Comment: Thank you luschn and CBroe for your quick replay, but actually i really need same as i expect with new line. i dont mind there is something like "enterkey" ascii or some other tag to use but important is need to make it working well. :(